# Image cosine wave

Tags: c#, winforms, math, trigonometry

I need help with this problem that I am having. What I am trying to do is make an image move in a cosine wave pattern in C# Windows Forms, but whatever I try never works. This is what I have so far in the timer

```
dblX = (Double)picture.Left;
dblY = (Double)picture.Top;
dblY = Math.Cos(dblX);
picture.Top = dblY;
picture.Left +=10;
```

What this does is make the image flash and go up and down very quickly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Math.Cos expects radians so you probably want Math.Cos(dblX * Math.PI / 180).

Answer (score 3):

[Math.Cos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) expects an argument in radians.

You are adding 10 radians each time.  There are 2 * PI radians in a cycle.

As your picture moves right you probably want to take the Cosine of `2 * PI * (left / total width)`

Comment: @user1033065 the width of the viewport or one cycle or some multiple thereof - how many cycles do you want to make?

Comment: I want it to be continuous, but even with converting it into radians, the image is still glitchy

Comment: Try adding say... `0.0001` instead of `10`. Also: How often is this being updated? That could be another large contributor to the problem.

Comment: @user1033065 How wide is the area the image is moving across and how many humps do you want to make?